# Yii validation tabular form can't upload files

Tags: php, yii

I'm having some problems when I try upload multiples files in multiples instances of my model (tabular way).

I have a model called Files and a view that generate a form for multiple instances of that model. When I save  the form without "multpart/form-data", everything works, but if I put this parameter on form and submit it, the validation shows the message that "File cannot be blank."

See my controller code bellow:

```
public function actionRegistration() {
  $company  = new Company;
  $contacts = $this->getModelItens('Contact', 3);
  $banks    = $this->getModelItens('Bank'   , 2);
  $files    = $this->getModelItens('File'   , 2);

  $company->scenario = 'create';
  if($_POST['Company']) {
    $company->attributes = $_POST['Company'];
    $valid = $company->validate();
    $valid = $this->validateModels($_POST['Contact'], $contacts) && $valid;
    $valid = $this->validateModels($_POST['Bank'], $banks) && $valid;
    $valid = $this->validateModels($_POST['File'], $files) && $valid;

    if($valid) {
      if($company->save()) {
        $this->saveModels($contacts, $company->id);
        $this->saveModels($banks, $company->id);
        $this->saveModels($files, $company->id);

        $this->redirect('/obrigado');
      }
    }
  }

    $this->render('registration', array('company' => $company, 'contacts' => $contacts, 'banks' => $banks, 'files' => $files));
  }


private function getModelItens($model_name, $times, $scenario = 'create') {
  $models = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) { 
    $models[$i]           = new $model_name; 
    $models[$i]->scenario = $scenario;
  }
  return $models;
}

private function validateModels($forms, $models) {
  $valid  = true;
  foreach($forms as $k => $form) { 
    $models[$k]->attributes = $form;
    $models[$k]->position   = $k;
    $valid = $models[$k]->validate() && $valid;
  }
  return $valid;
}

private function saveModels($models, $company_id) {
  foreach($models as $k => $model) {
    $model->company_id = $company_id;
    if($model instanceOf File) {
      if($model->save()) $this->upload_file($model, "file"); 
    } else $model->save();
  }
}


private function upload_file($model, $field, $k) {
  $path = Yii::app()->basePath . "/../assets/files/companies/{$model->company_id}/";

  $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, $field);
  if($file instanceof CUploadedFile) $model->$field = $file;

  if($model->$field instanceof CUploadedFile) {
    if(!file_exists($path)) exec("mkdir -p {$path}");
    $model->$field->saveAs($path . $model->$field);
  }
}
```

I've  tried everything but I can't fix it, any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this assignment `$models[$k]->attributes = $form;` will do the $_FILES as well as the $_POST for your model. Looking at [this example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/), I think you need to do that `CUploadedFile` stuff before you `validate()` or `save()` (which also validates), otherwise your file field will be blank.

I think you need this order of events:

1. `$model->$field = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, $field);` // set file field
2. `$model->save()` OR `$model->validate()` // THEN validate
3. `$model->$field->saveAs($path . $model->$field);` // then save the file

Instead, you have this order of events currently:

1. `$model->save()` AND `$model->validate()`
2. `$model->$field = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, $field);`
3. `$model->$field->saveAs($path . $model->$field);`

I could be way off though, I'm just looking at your code and not actually testing this. Also, I have no idea why it only throws an error when you set the `multpart/form-data` attribute on the form; it should not work at all without that! Maybe it was skipping validation on the file fields without that? Or `attributes()` was assigning something from $_POST besides the file? /shrug

**UPDATE:**
Another thing that might be happening, is that with "tabular" input you need to reference the input field with the '$key' as well (i.e. `Model[0][imageFile]`). So here, where you are calling:

```
$this->upload_file($model, "file");`
```

You probably need to call something like this, so that `getInstanceByName()` is getting the right field name:

```
$this->upload_file($model, "[".$k."]file");`
```

I think you will still need to re-arrange your code as I mention above too.

Good luck!

More reading:

1. [Yii forum post about this subject](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/17953-uploading-file-not-validate-when-tabular-input/)
2. [Your same question in the Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/24334-upload-files-using-tabular-form/)

Comment: Hi, thaddeusmt, I have already made this test, and not work :(, I think that there isn't a way to upload files using CUploadedFile and tabular input. have you another suggestion?

Comment: Well, "tabular" input with files *is* possible, I've done this before. I added another suggestion above for you to investigate. Cheers